# python shutil ioerror when using the ~ symbol in filepaths

Tags: python, shutil, ioerror

Python's `shutil` seems unable to use the `~` symbol for filepaths. This is a common key to use and yet shutil seems to be unable to find the files when this is in the filepath:

**where:**

```
file2copy
Out[5]: '~/folder1/folder2/file.txt'
```

**this error is produced:**

```
  File "/home/user/script.py", line 1192, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(file2copy, newpath+'/newfilename.txt')

  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/rootclone/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)

  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/rootclone/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/folder1/folder2/file.txt'
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or simply that `~` keys can't be used in python. Hoping for some resolution to this. I know that I can use exact filepaths to solve this but the `~` key is useful for changing between users etc (without having to reset working directories etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is a shell construct.

You should use `os.path.expanduser()`, e.g.:

```
os.path.expanduser('~/folder1/folder2/file.txt')
```

Will result in something like:

```
'/home/username/folder1/folder2/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative path to the user you are trying to use, cannot be used, as it will literally interpret the "~" symbol as part of the string, and not like the terminal interprets it.

In your case you actually have to put full path tho file.

And that would be something like:

```
/home/user/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```